# can't customize drop down menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

when you click on hamburger on mobile view, dropdown menu appears. But i can't find it using Chrome DevTools. 
Could you help me to find it?

The website –> [link](http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/) (password K1k0r1)

[image: you can see the menu on this screenshot]

But where it is located within code?

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You need to reduce the size of the browser.

Comment: That's a native dropdown using a `<select>` element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<select class="selectnav" id="selectnav1"><option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/#about-kikori">About Kikori</option><option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/#kumamoto">- KUMAMOTO</option><option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/#earth">- EARTH</option><option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/#water">- WATER</option><option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/#time">- TIME</option><option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/#the-woodsman">- THE WOODSMAN</option><option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/store-locator/">Where to buy</option><option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/news-reviews/" selected="">News</option><option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/recipes/">Recipes</option><option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/tag/kikori-whiskey-review/">Reviews</option><option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/contact/">Contact</option></select>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz1Ay.png)

Answer (score 0):

check this html snippets:[image] which show the html and css used in drop down.

Answer (score -1):

Here it is in the code. Its just under your regular navigation menu. you will only see it on mobile or if you resize the window.

```
<select class="selectnav" id="selectnav1">
<option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/#about-kikori">ABOUT KIKORI</option>
<option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/#kumamoto">- KUMAMOTO</option>
<option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/#earth">- EARTH</option>
<option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/#water">- WATER</option>
<option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/#time">- TIME</option>
<option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/#the-woodsman">- THE WOODSMAN</option>
<option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/store-locator/">WHERE TO BUY</option>
<option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/news-reviews/">NEWS</option>
<option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/recipes/">RECIPES</option><option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/tag/kikori-whiskey-review/">REVIEWS</option>
<option value="http://dig.katherineblumkin.com/contact/">CONTACT</option>
</select>
```

I think thats what you are looking for.